# Why does MySQL return error on creating a table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

I've been trying to create a table with user input name but I get an error no matter how I write the query.

right now query is like this:

```
query=("CREATE TABLE "+t+" ( NAME VARCHAR , DISTANCE VARCHAR , PRICE VARCHAR , LOCATION VARCHAR)")
```

and after running the whole code it returns:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', DISTANCE VARCHAR , PRICE VARCHAR , LOCATION VARCHAR)' at line 1
```

I also tried other ways like using `%s`:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE %s (NAME VARCHAR, DISTANCE VARCHAR, PRICE VARCHAR, LOCATION VARCHAR)"%(t))
```

or `{}` on replacing the table name:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE {} (NAME VARCHAR, DISTANCE VARCHAR, PRICE VARCHAR, LOCATION VARCHAR)".format(t)
```

All codes return the same error.
Also tried changing columns names and datatypes. I'd be thankful if somebody could help me.

Comment: In all of this, you haven't shown `t`

Comment: Please (please please) read up and *understand* the security implications of SQL injection; which can be introduced using string formatting and concatenation. [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) provides a nice (albeit comedic) example.

Comment: @S3DEV you cannot parameterize table names. You _have_ to use string formatting in some way

Comment: Yes, of course.  However, a USP can be used which can internalise the concatenation; although understandably a bit advanced for this case.  *To the OP:* However, dynamic table naming should be a *rare* occurrence only under *controlled* circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

Be sure your variable `t` is a string.

Second:

You have to declare a size for your `VARCHAR`, so a max width for your string. Try:

```
query=("CREATE TABLE "+t+" ( NAME VARCHAR(90) , DISTANCE VARCHAR(90) , PRICE varchar(90) , LOCATION VARCHAR(90))")
```

Comment: It worked! but the new question is why it didn't work when I put max width of 255? was it too big?

Comment: MySQL has a max size for one row, but 255 should be okay. What says the error message?

Comment: same error it showed for the main problem.

Comment: Have you dropped the table before creating a new one if they are named the same?

Comment: I used an if statement to check if it exists otherwise create one.